# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.DateTime>' to 'System.DateTime'

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I want to select a datetime format data from database.

I have 3 models.

```
School

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SchoolStore> SchoolStores { get; set; }
```

```
SchoolStores

        public int SchoolId { get; set; }

        public School School { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
```

```
Events

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public EventStatus Status { get; set; }
```

The method looks like

```cs
 public IQueryable<SchoolProjectionModel> GetAllForList()
        {
            return dataContext.Schools.AsNoTracking().IgnoreQueryFilters()
                .Select(s => new SchoolListProjectionModel()
                {                 
                  publishedEventDate = s.SchoolStores.Select(ss => ss.Events
                                                      .Where(ee => ee.Status == EventStatus.Published && ee.SchoolId == s.Id)
                                                       .Select(ed => ed.Date)
                                                        .Where(ses => ses.Date >= DateTime.Today))

                });
        }
```

But I receive such error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.DateTime>' 
to 'System.DateTime'
```

I'm expecting to receive datetime format data from database.

SchoolListProjectionModel

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
    public class SchoolListProjectionModel
    {

        public DateTime publishedEventDate { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Please show us `SchoolListProjectionModel`

Comment: updated my question with model

Comment: After the last `.where` add either `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Just replace the .Where(condition) with a .FirstOrDefault(condition) to get a single date and not a list of dates

Comment: I tried to add and replace but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
                publishedEventDate = s.SchoolStores.SelectMany(ss => ss.Events
                                                        .Where(e => e.Status == EventStatus.Published && e.SchoolId == s.Id)
                                                                .Select(ed => ed.Date)
                                                                        .Where(eed => eed.Date >= DateTime.Today && eed.Date != null)).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
              publishedEventDate = s.SchoolStores.Select(ss => ss.Events
                                                  .Where(ee => ee.Status == EventStatus.Published && ee.SchoolId == s.Id && ee.Date >= DateTime.Today).Select(p=>p.Date)).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: @zeng tian You should add some explanation as well.